# Qual a diferença entre o uso de @Transient e transient em um atributo de uma entidade JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

Estudando alguns códigos de terceiros, me deparei com diferentes formas de definir que um determinado atributo de uma Entidade não será relacionado a uma coluna no banco de dados.

Dentre as formas que encontrei, a primeira usa a anotação `@Transient` logo acima da linha de declaração da propriedade (Exemplo 1) e a segunda é incorporada `transient` na própria linha de declaração da propriedade (Exemplo 2).

**Exemplo 1:**

```
@Transient
private int idValidacao;
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```
private transient int idValidacao;
```

Qual a diferença entre essas duas formas de se declarar um atributo como `transient` e suas vantagens e desvantagens entre um e outro?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@Transient` é uma [anotação do JPA](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) e está relacionada diretamente com persistência de dados. Campos marcados com esta anotação não serão considerados em inserts, updates... gerados pelo framework.

`transient` é um [modificador do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3), que deve ser utilizado para marcar campos que não devem ser considerados no processo de serialização, ao serializar dados da classe para um arquivo, ou para rede por exemplo.

Elas possuem propósitos diferentes, e sua utilização também é diferente.

Answer (score 2):

A anotação `@Transient` pode ser utilizada no atributo de uma classe, ou em um método `get`, no seu caso `getIdValidacao()`. A forma como é estabelecida tem relação com uma anotação à classe, sendo `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` para estar em um atributo, ou `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` para método.

Ao contrário disto, porém servindo para o mesmo propósito, existe uma das palavras reservadas da linguagem Java, a `transient`, e ela não tem nenhuma relação com a especificação JPA, e sim com a interface `java.io.Serializable`.

Quando uma classe é assinalada com esta interface, algo místico acontece, métodos não apresentados na assinatura da interface, `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)` e `readObject(ObjectInputStream)`, surgem sem o seu consentimento para uma possível serialização, mas o quê é isto?

Ainda que utilizando JPA em seu projeto, utilizar `transient` pode ajudá-lo a aliviar o armazenamento de objetos em memória durante a execução de `@Stateful` Enterprise Java Beans (EJB), ou até mesmo escopos Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI) que não sejam `@RequestScoped`, pois o propósito da serialização em si é armazenar arquivos em memória, ainda que não estejam sendo utilizados, como neste cenário, ou para um possível registro em arquivos.

É importante informar um `serialVersionUID` para que os objetos em memória, os POJOs, não se confundam por conta própria, e quando for salvá-los em arquivo, recomenda-se a utilização de um Serialization Proxy, mencionado por Joshua Bloch no livro Effective Java.